# Allow communication between Services?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

We are working on a number of services, lets say `PersonService`, `InsuranceService` and `PaycheckService`. To access these services through an API there is a controller.

There are situations where the `PaycheckService` needs information about a `Person`. 
Currently we're using a layer between `Controller` and `Service` to:

- Get information from PersonService
- Get information from PaycheckService
- Combine and return result.

Which is working at this moment but as more services are created the dependency between services is increased. This results in more logic (magic?) in this *'between layer'*.

I've been reading Fowler on the subject of Dependency Injection and Service Locator which could be useful. (we do use Unity for IoC and DI here and there for shared functionality)

The question is what is a good strategy to let services consume other services?

(Messaging, Injection, REST,..)

[image: Visual]

Comment: Two questions: (1) Why do you need "PersonService" and (2) why would it not possible for "PaychecService" to own just those parts of information on  a person it needs. You might think of sharing a person's identity (i.e. ID) between services, but let each service own and maintain all the data it needs to make its business decisions and thus stay autonomous.

Comment: 1) The Person and Paycheck service are just examples. 2) It would in this simplified example, the real application has many domains with corresponding services. It would be a bad decision to let each domain just query whatever it needs just to be done with it.

Comment: When I mentioned "own the data", this means not querying, but owning and managing the data it needs to perform its business. An Id that is shared can then be used to correlate an entity between services, without needing to rely on some type of shared model of the entity. Each domain can have its own model of an entity containing only what it needs. Keeping services focused, independent and isolated. I.e. not a data model that is shared between services.

Comment: Ok. But this will result in duplicate business logic? I mean this will result in two services owning and managing the data for Person information.

Comment: Let's try an example. Suppose we have a ShippingService, an OrderService and a BillingService. All of these deal with the same "order" entity and the same "customer" entity, but this entity means something different to each of them and they all need different parts of information from this entity in order to fulfill their business responsibilities. ShippingAddresses related to the customer id would be owned by the ShippingService, but a BillingAddress would be owned by the BillingService, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it helps, will be doing some rethinking

Answer (score 2):

You could create a single component that has the responsibility to facilitate the location of a service based on the contract it provides.

This way a service only needs to know the contract it wants to consume and the service locator.

The locator can be anything, ranging from a class that reads a configuration list from a network share to a central service that reads configuration from a durable store or uses [WS-Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791.aspx) to track services.

In addition you might want to create/design a shared set of data contracts that specify the types/messages exchanged between services. This way you lessen the burden of translating between types used in the services.

**EDIT**

You added to your question:

> (Messaging, Injection, REST,..)
>
> Requirements: Fast, loosely coupled

To be honest, I do think that this addition is not very useful because these are no strategies but are patterns and tools that could help implement the design.

Also, the requirements are not very helpful because we do not know what you consider to be fast nor what feature of being loosely coupled is most important to you.

If you are looking for specific guidance try to make the question more specific or try to build something and ask questions about what you run into.

Answer (score 1):

Your services should be autonomous. They should not communicate each other. You shoud think like every single service is a completely independent product that can be used in other projects or it can serve itself to other companies for different purposes.

If ServiceY needs some data from ServiceX, ServiceY shoud get that data as input, it shoud not connect other services to get data.

You can put a facade (or facades) in front of your services to orchestrate your services.  This facade will be actually your Application's high level business that includes workflows like first get data from ServiceY than give that data to ServiceX and get result from X etc.

If your services are not web services and just components in your business layer of app, they should be autonomous and should not use each other and Controller can be your facade to orchestrate your service components.

Comment: The services do communicate with external services (other suppliers, AD, Reporting,..) why not communicate with internal services? We do have a facade at this moment which is beginning to look like getting more logic to bind services together (see ref to magic in between layer).

Comment: A service should not communicate with other services. Communication is not business, it is a different responsibility to be implemented on an other class or module or subsystem.. A service's responsibility should be a particular piece of business logic not more.. ( <S> OLID)

Comment: Usually I put external webservice as repository. Logically, it access outside data source.